# How to evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I compute this limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x}\text{?}$$

My solution is here:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x}=\dfrac{1-1}{1-1} = \dfrac{0}{0}$$

I used L'H$\hat{\mathrm{o}}$pital's rule:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{12^x\ln12-4^x\ln4}{9^x\ln9-3^x\ln3}&=\dfrac{\ln12-\ln4}{\ln9-\ln3}
\\ &=\dfrac{\ln(12/4)}{\ln(9/3)}
\\ &=\dfrac{\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}
\\ &=1
\end{align*}
My answer comes out to be $1$. Can I evaluate this limit without L'H$\hat{\mathrm{o}}$pital's rule? Thanks.

Comment: Since numerator is of the form $A-B$ where $A, B$ tend to $1$ we can replace them by their logarithm. Similarly do for denominator. Cancelling $x$ you get the answer.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajput Please don't use the displaymode in titles. I hope you know this is discouraged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A variation of other answers (that more closely parallels a common pattern when the numerator and denominator are polynomials) is "big part factoring".  \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{12^x - 4^x}{9^x-3^x}
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{12^x \left(1 - \left( \frac{4}{12} \right) ^x \right)}{9^x \left( 1-\left( \frac{3}{9} \right) ^x \right) }  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{12^x \left(1 - \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) ^x \right)}{9^x \left( 1-\left( \frac{1}{3} \right) ^x \right) }  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{12^x }{9^x}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{1}  \\
    &= 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can evaluate the limit without LHospital's rule as follows
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{4^x\left(\left(\frac{12}{4}\right)^x-1\right)}{3^x\left(\left(\frac93\right)^x-1\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{4^x\left(3^x-1\right)}{3^x(3^x-1)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^x$$
$$=\color{blue}{1}$$

Comment: Oof beaten by 5 seconds. Brutal haha. Note that this can all be done without the limit until the first step since the algebraic operations are completely well-defined. $+1$

Comment: I have thought  the exact same thing: 12 was multiple of 4 and 9 was multiple of 3. :-)

Comment: I'm not fond either of carrying the limit operator all along, just use $A=B=\cdots=C\xrightarrow{x\to 0}\ell$ with `\xrightarrow{x\to 0}`

Comment: @zwim Thanks! That's good idea

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot *very arguably*: where you went wrong : before rushing to use L'Hopital's rule, take a step back, examine the numerator and denominator, and look for a common factor.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use
$$a^{x} = e^{x \ln(a)} = 1 + x\ln(a) + \frac{x^2\ln^{2}(a)}{2!}  + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})$$
therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{a^{x} - b^{x}}{c^{x} - d^{x}} &= \frac{x\,(\ln(a) - \ln(b)) + \frac{x^2}{2} \, (\ln^{2}(a) - \ln^{2}(b))  + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})}{x\,(\ln(c) - \ln(d)) + \frac{x^2}{2} \, (\ln^{2}(c) - \ln^{2}(d)) + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})} \\
&= \frac{\ln(\frac{a}{b}) + \frac{x}{2} \, \ln(a b)\,\ln(\frac{a}{b})   + \mathcal{O}(x^{2})}{\ln(\frac{c}{d}) + \frac{x}{2} \, \ln(c d)\,\ln(\frac{c}{d})   + \mathcal{O}(x^{2})}
\end{align}

Taking the limit as $x \to 0$ gives
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{a^{x} - b^{x}}{c^{x} - d^{x}} = \frac{\ln(\frac{a}{b})}{\ln(\frac{c}{d})} $$

hence for your limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x}=\frac{\ln(\frac{12}{4})}{\ln(\frac{9}{3})}=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

It could be amazing to get more than the limit itself for the most general case. Replacing $t^x$ by $e^{x \log(t)}$, using Taylor and long division would give
$$\frac{a^x-b^x}{c^x-d^x}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}+\frac 12\frac{\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \log \left(\frac{a b}{c d}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}x+O(x^2)$$ which shows the limit and also hoaw it is approached.

Answer (score 2):

If you add and subtract $1$ from numerator and denominator
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(12^x-1)-(4^x-1)}{(9^x-1)-(3^x-1)}
$$
then dividing each term by $x$
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{12^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{4^x-1}{x}}{\dfrac{9^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}}
$$
Now, all four limits have the form
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log a
$$
so we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{12^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{4^x-1}{x}}{\dfrac{9^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}}=\frac{\log12-\log4}{\log9-\log3}=\frac{\log3}{\log3}=1
$$

Comment: Well done, this is exactly L'Hospital.

Comment: @YvesDaoust my aim was to build expressions of type $$\frac{a^x-1}{x}$$ to use the corresponding special limit in $0$, that is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$ and does not require derivatives. Here, students are able to solve this limit in this way before even knowing about derivatives and L'Hospital.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-a^0}x$ *is* a derivative and a derivative *is* virtually equivalent to L'Hospital. Hence you can very well use this example to introduce these two concepts :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using L'Hopital's rule by the properties of logarithms:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left( \ln\dfrac{12^x-4^x}{9^x-3^x} \right)$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left( \ln (12^x-4^x) - \ln(9^x-3^x) \right)$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left( (\ln 4^x + \ln(3^x - 1))- (\ln3^x + \ln(3^x - 1)) \right)$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left(\ln(4^x) - \ln(3^x) \right)$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \exp \left(x \ln 4 - x \ln 3 \right)$$
$$=  \exp(0) = \boxed{1}.$$

See, no fractions! Except for the first line which is a rephrasing of the problem statement, of course.